# Adobe DTM Custom Page Load Rule to fire only for iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, rules, adobe-analytics

I have a Page inside which i have an iFrame that has some steps to be done

Now I want a page load rule to fire only for my frame inside the page.

My page URls and iFrame Urls are different, I have the DTM scripts at both page level and frame level

Comment: Are you able to provide a [minimum, complete, verifiable example of your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I have page with URL www.kksksk.com and an iFrame (with multiplepages)  embeded in it ( sample URLwww.xxxx.com/add.do?select='inputText'). I have DTM scripts both at Page level and IFrame level. Now i want Page load rule to be setup only at the frame level and track all the pages only inside the iFrame

Answer (score 0):

Managing code between a typical page and iFrame can be tricky.

I would suggest aborting the default iFrame page view call (s.abort = true) in the AA tool custom code and instead, use a direct call PV rule that can be called and managed any time there is PV activity within the iFrame.

Hope this helps.